# UV Unwrap messed up

Tags: uv, baking

**Hello Gents**

How can i delete the selected unwraps on the left without destroying the model and the ones on the right ?

I unwrapped two times by accident.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any problems with that unwrap. When you pressed A you deselected the mesh, so did the UV map which only shows for selected faces unless you enable *Keep UV mode and selection in sync* button in UV/Image editor which is not enabled in your case.

Comment: You nearly answered my question ! Because there are two unwraps on picture, noticed after i enabled (keep Sync) The Question now is, how do i delete unwraps in the UV window ?

Comment: As long as a mesh has a UVMap, every face needs a projection. You can only reset it to default by "space -> reset" in Image Editor or "u -> reset" in 3D View, which will be like a triangle or quad cover the whole image. Resetting the image can be done by selecting and unlinking in Image Editor. Is that what you want?

Comment: In your Image, on the right in the Properties panel > UV maps > maybe all you want to do is select one of the two UV maps listed there and hit the minus button to delete it ? I don't know how you are getting two different UV maps to show at the same time in the UV/Image editing window ?